# Multiple cells selection, not range

Tags: vba, excel, loops, cells

I want to loop through every row and do some actions for multiple cells selected, e.g. `K3,N3,Q3,T3,W3,Z3` next `K4,N4,Q4...` etc.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub Colors_test()
    For counter = 3 To 110
    Range("K" & counter, "N" & counter, "Q" & counter, "T" & _
         counter, "W" & counter, "Z" & counter).Select

    Selection.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
        xlConditionValueLowestValue
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
        .Color = 7039480
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = _
        xlConditionValuePercentile
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
        .Color = 8711167
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = _
        xlConditionValueHighestValue
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
        .Color = 8109667
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Next counter
    MsgBox "Ok All " & counter
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the problem? Please quote the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass in the range as 1 argument.  Try this:

```
Range("K" & counter & ",N" & counter & ",Q" & counter & ",T" & counter & ",W" & counter & ",Z" & counter).Select
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to loop. You can use the below code.

```
Sub Colors_test()


    With Range("K3:K110,N3:N110,Q3:Q110,T3:T110,W3:W110,Z3:Z110")
        .Select
      // your code here

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a much better solution. No need for a loop.